# JS sort different behaviour in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I'm running a basic sort in both Chrome and Firefox, and I see two different results. It seems like Firefox ignores values.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id": "a"
  },
  {
    "id": "b"
  },
  {
    "id": "c"
  },
  {
    "id": "d"
  },
  {
    "id": "e"
  },
  {
    "id": "f"
  },
  {
    "id": "g"
  },
  {
    "id": "h"
  }
]

const sorted = data.slice().sort((project) => {
  console.log(project.id)
  return project.id === 'h' ? -1 : 0;
})

console.log(sorted[0].id === 'h');
```

Results:

Firefox - `false`

Chrome - `true`

Is there a bug in Firefox?

Comment: If you sort a collection you're supposed to compare two elements of that collection with each other. That's also the reason why the callback of `.sort()` is supposed to accept two arguments.

Comment: Please read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description).

Comment: How this answer the question? you see that Chrome returns true and Firefox isn't

Comment: I think the specific sorting algorithm is implementation dependent, so there is no guarantee that the values are visited in the same order in different browsers. Therefore you might get different results if you use the API incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a bug in Firefox?

No. The [specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort) says:

> If `comparefn` is not `undefined` and is not a *consistent comparison function* for the elements of this array (see below), the sort order is *implementation-defined*.

In other words, if you don't provide a proper comparison function, then the resulting order can differ between browsers.

Further down it explains what a *consistent comparison function* is. Among other things it specifies that the following needs to hold true:

> a = a (reflexivity)

But that's not the case for your comparison function. Because you are ignoring the second argument, if `{"id": "h"}` is compared to itself, you will also return `-1`, indicating that the element is smaller than itself, and thus violating the aforementioned rule.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers use different sort algorithms. This affects which order elements in the array will be passed into the callback function you pass to `sort()`.

The callback function takes **two** arguments (the two values that are being compared) and should return something to indicate if they are the same or which one should be first.

```
sort( function (a, b) { return 1 || 0 || -1 } )
```

Your code will sort `"h"` towards the start of the array if, and only if, it is passed in to `a`.

If the sort algorithm passes it into `b` then you'll leave it where it is.