# sort function unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript

i am trying to understand array sorting method , the problem i am currently facing is when i am declaring some variables inside compare function its not sorting the same as it is doing without those variables although those variables are not used anywhere

**can anyone explain what is actually happening here**

also i find out that sort functions behave different in firefox and chrome
[page_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113002/js-sort-different-behaviour-in-firefox-and-chrome) i am testing this in firefox dev edition

[image: browser_screenshot]

```js
let list1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"]

list1.sort((a,b)=>{
    let pat = ["d","a"]
    return b - a
})
console.log(list1) // Array(9) [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i" ]

let list2 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"]

list2.sort((a,b)=>{
    // let pat = ["d","a"]
    return b - a
})
console.log(list2) // Array(9) [ "i", "h", "g", "f", "e", "d", "c", "b", "a" ]
```

Comment: @Andy see i have updated my code still same

Comment: you declare `let pat` but why?

Comment: @MaikLowrey actually i am trying to make a compare function where pat items will be listed first as a practice but while defining it i have noticed that its behaving different

Comment: ok. i understood. i wrote a answer two point you out that you make a other approach to archive this.

Comment: @AmirRahman You can consider checking out my answer as well, I've added snippets to explain how you can prepend values after sorting the `list`.

Comment: @AmirRahman Do you want to sort `pat` list as well, or you just want to prepend it as it is?

Comment: but i still didn't get it why defining an array is giving two different results although i understood i cant use (a - b) it will be break but then why its not breaking one function and breaking another sorry if it is too messed up but i am little confused here

Comment: @AmirRahman Also, I've added one more snippet to my answer do check that out, I think that's what your goal is!

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee yes i am getting different results with updated question and thanks for your answer its helpfull i would like to see some more suggestions from others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `"a" - "b"` it evaluates to `NaN` which is incorrect as that's not what you intended and also inconsistent (varies browser to browser).

Either don't pass a callback to `sort` in which case it does the following:

> The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the sorted array. The default sort order is ascending, built upon converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values.

Or you can use [String.prototype.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
let list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"];

console.log([...list].sort());

console.log([...list].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)));
```

If you want to prepend some values to the sorted array you'll have to do it separately you can't do it using `sort`.

```js
let list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"];

let pat = ["x", "y"];

let sortedList = [...list].sort();

let patAppendedSortedList = [...pat, ...sortedList];

console.log(patAppendedSortedList);
```

And if you want to sort both the `list` and `pat` but you want to keep all `pat` elements before all `list` elements then consider the snippet below.

```js
let list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"];

let pat = ["z", "x", "y"];

let patSet = new Set(pat);

let sortedList = [...pat, ...list].sort((a, b) => {
  // If a has higher priority put it before b
  if (patSet.has(a) && !patSet.has(b)) {
    return -1;
  }
  // If b has higher priority put it before a
  if (patSet.has(b) && !patSet.has(a)) {
    return 1;
  }

  // Otherwise both a and b have same priority
  // Sort them according to their value
  return a.localeCompare(b);
});

console.log(sortedList);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you subtract a string from another string, it will attempt to convert the strings to numbers.

All of your strings will convert to `NaN`.

`NaN-NaN` is also `NaN`.

So it doesn't matter which two values from your array you are comparing, your comparison function will always return `NaN`.

(Note that a comparison function is supposed to return a number that is `0`, greater than `0` or less than `0` *and* be consistent for any given pair of values. The one you are using is just broken for the data you are using).

The order the letters get sorted into therefore depends on the order in which they are compared to each other (because your comparison function is broken).

That order is determined by the sort algorithm that the JS engine uses. This is an implementation detail that the specification doesn't mandate.

One browser might use a quick sort while another might use a bubble sort. Hence you get different results.

---

Write a comparison function which isn't nonsense to get consistent results.

The *default* comparison function is find for lexical sorting under most circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Now i understood your goal. But you cant archive this with your way. You cant make some prepends of values in the JS sort function. You have to make it in two steps. 1.) sort 2.) prepend your pat values to the sorted array.

```js
const list = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"];

const pat = ["d","a"]; 
const sorted = [...pat, ...list.sort()];

console.log(sorted)
```